# Injecting DAO dependencies into Service Class in Core Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, dependencies

We don't have any frameworj like Spring where we can inject dependencies using annotations or xml file.
We have handler classes, service classes and dao classes.

Handler classes access service which perform business logic to get the data to be persisted into the db using dao layer.

Now I have seen that in our project we are adding the dao dependencies in the Service class by declaring them as shown below:

TestService.java

```
Class ServiceImpl{

    private static final TestAccessor accessor = TestAcceessor.Instance;

}
```

Here the `TestAcceessor` is an `enum` and is made Singleton.

My questions are as follows:

1. > Is implementing the Accessors singleton using enum and then declaring
   >   them as shown above(`static final`) means there is no tight coupling
   >   between our project's `Service` class and `DAO` class?

   IMO there is no tight coupling as we are just accessing the enum constant and any change to `DAO` enum doesn't make us change the service class.
2. > Since we are accessing `Service` classes from `Handler` classes, how can
   >   we inject DAO dependencies if required into service(We don't use
   >   Spring) class?

   IMO we don't want to do that from Handler as that would expose our `DAO` classes to `Handler` and thus make them insecure.

Comment: How do you test #1? In other words, what do you for testing services without real DB access? If you can't, then Yes, you are tightly coupled to `TestAcceessor.Instance`

Comment: How do you instanciate Services in #2?

Comment: @Laiv thanks for the comment regarding #1. Actually we need our db instance to be running to test the #1 i.e. our service classes.

Comment: @Laiv our services are stateless. They only implement functions. This is done to avoid multithreading related issues. So we can directly access our services using `ServiceName.methodName()`.

Comment: Sorry to say but #2 demands injection, making the Handler aware of the DAO. Unless you inject the service into the handler or you expose the service to a 3rd component, from the Handler itself.

Comment: @Laiv from your comment regarding #1 I understood that for something to be called loosely coupled, we must be able to test it independently.For this in our class we should be injecting the dependencies so that we can use mocking tools s.a Mockito to mock them and thus making testing independent of dependencies. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Testing is a good hint. A very important one. It should be possible for you to replace the DAO any time. Singletons and constants don't get along with that. Ideally, yes getting injected the dependencies make a big deal. Are you familiar with Dependency inversion and dependency injection?

Comment: Got your point. In my project even though the DAO's are singleton and they are declared as static, final but since we need the db instance to be up and running to be able to test the classes having accessors to dao, our classes are tightly coupled to DAO. I assume this is meant by last statement in your last comment.So if we remove this dependency on Db instance then can we say that our class is now loosely coupled to the DAO?

Comment: If you can replace/change the DAO instance without having to change the service (any time), yes. Note that the DI is highly recommended to make the solution more testable. The more testable the better. Solutions should be first testable and then everything else (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this code:

```
Class ServiceImpl{

    private static final TestAccessor accessor = TestAcceessor.Instance;

}
```

ServiceImple **knows** it's being tested? It always gets a `TestAccessor`?

The [pure dependency injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) version of this code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestAccessor testAccessor = new TestAccessor();
    ServiceImple service = new ServiceImple(testAccessor);

    service.start();
}

Class ServiceImpl{

    ServiceImpl(Accessor accessor){
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }
    Accessor accessor;

    ...
}
```

Here `serviceImple` has no idea what kind of Accessor it's using or where to find it. You can feed it anything it knows how to talk to. You don't have to change any globally located anything to do that.

Now you don't have to do it this way. But, using the locating method:

Show me how you do polymorphism.

The fact that your classes have no state means nothing to me. I make stateless instances all the time. Doesn't hurt a thing. Instance state isn't the only reason to have an instance. The ability to polymorphically deploy messages (events and commands) is also important. Tell me how you do that.

Injecting doesn't mean locating. You are not using dependency injection. You are using a [service locator](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). Yours is just distributed as static method getters.

> IMO there is no tight coupling as we are just accessing the enum constant and any change to DAO enum doesn't make us change the service class.

That still means you're stuck with one service class. That's the coupling. The coupling is in the form that things KNOW where to find their dependencies. Done this way you can't achieve polymorphism by simply handing them different things. You have to change whats where they expect to find their dependencies. That makes achieving polymorphism difficult because if you change the dependency that where your class expects to find it you've changed that dependency for *everything* that uses it. That's called a global. Reasoning about the impact of messing with them is hard.

People often trot out testability as the argument against this kind of coupling but that misses the real point. There are many frameworks that use reflection tricks unshoot yourself in the foot when you work this way. These bandaids aren't going to heal the bullet wound of global dependencies.

Not knowing where your dependencies come from is nice because now finding them is not your problem. It means you can focus on using the dependencies. It means you know what you're using was meant for you because they were given specifically to you.

Doesn't that just move the problem somewhere else? Yes it does. You can create everything in `main()` and inject from there. You can a simple factory method that locates the dependencies and then injects them. What? Yes I said locates. Locating isn't evil. It's just best done by construction code in classes/moduals/main that doesn't have to know how to use anything. This is the [separate use from construction](http://www.netobjectives.net/files/books/esad/essential-skills-separate-use-from-construction.pdf) principle. It's important enough that if you do use static methods to build instances they shouldn't hang off the same class name that instantiate unless you know some damn good default dependencies.

You shouldn't make it unimaginable to write a different static factory method that builds the instance with different dependencies. This should be no more difficult then giving the new factory a good name.

Show me how you have the ability to separate use and construction decisions like this I'll forget about [pure dependency injection](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/11/19/how-to-use-pure-di/). Show me how you do polymorphism.

> > Since we are accessing Service classes from Handler classes, how can we inject DAO dependencies if required into service(We don't use Spring) class?
>
> IMO we don't want to do that from Handler as that would expose our DAO classes to Handler and thus make them insecure.

Unless you have a `SecurityManager` Hanging DAO's off static finals wont secure them either thanks to [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection). Just because you want to control access to something doesn't mean it has to exist in only one place or only have one form.

Look into [GuardedObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/GuardedObject.html) to control access to an object. Then you can pass it to whatever.